# Make a wizard on ASP.NET site

Tags: c#, asp.net, wizard

I'm absolutely new in ASP.NET.

I've got a web site running under umbraco cms (ASP.NET). I need to create a simple wizard: step by step user will answer questions using simple controls (checkboxes, dropdown lists, radiobuttons, textboxes, etc.). Some steps depends on previous answers, some of them doesn't.

So, I've got 2 questions on this:

1. What is the best practice to create wizard on ASP.NET web site? I looked at  System.Web.UI.WebControls.Wizard class [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.wizard.aspx) but I'm not sure it's a good approach to mix asp.net controls and html markup together, especially paying attention to the fact, that every step of the wizard is described in one huge markup file.
2. I've got the samples of html markup of wizard steps (static aspx pages). That's why I want to divide html and logic. I want to be able to apply new design and markup in the future, not changing code. What is the best approach for this - dividing html and c# code?

Examples are welcome.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean: not good approach to mix asp.net controls and html markup? I think ASP.NET Wizard Control is good for your purpose: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15804/ASP-NET-2-0-Wizard-Control and http://weblogs.asp.net/sreejukg/archive/2012/01/21/walkthrough-wizard-control-in-asp-net.aspx

Comment: btw, I don't know umbraco, but maybe they have some add-on for this task?